# Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/tensorflow-gpu/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using ubuntu.

I want to install `tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0`

```
python3.7 -m pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
```

I got this erro:

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/tensorflow-gpu/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/tensorflow-gpu/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/tensorflow-gpu/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/tensorflow-gpu/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/tensorflow-gpu/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/tensorflow-gpu/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/tensorflow-gpu/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

also I doing but this command:

```
python3.7 -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
```

but I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Update the file below with this:

```
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.python.org
           pypi.org
           files.pythonhosted.org
```

file location

MacOS - $HOME/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf

Unix - $HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf

Windows - %APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini